# Joomla Ajax Request Error

Tags: ajax, module, joomla3.0

I got following error

> Method get_slotsAjax does not exist

my call in healper file

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","?option=com_ajax&module=quickcontact&method=get_slots&format=json",true);
```

my function call

```
public function get_slots()
{
 ....
}
```

Went by this [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface).

What am I Missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your method name must end with "Ajax" as mentioned in the documentation.

> NOTE: All methods must end in Ajax.

For example:

> method=mySuperAwesomeMethodToTrigger will call
>   mySuperAwesomeMethodToTriggerAjax

So your method name would be as there in the error

> get_slotsAjax